# Give object name of a variable string

Tags: c#, string, object, foreach, objectname

I want to give an object a name that's changes all the time. I have a foreach in which I set a pushpin. Each time there is being looped through the foreach, I want there to be a new name based on whats in my list (I'm looping through my list).

for example, this is my code:

```
Test test = new Test();
        foreach (var test in Test.allTests)
        {
            Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
        }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
   Test test = new Test();
            foreach (var test in Test.allTests)
            {
                Pushpin test.testname = new Pushpin();
            }
```

I am unable to do this, because test.testname is a string..

Comment: Any particular reason why a `Dictionary<string, Pushpin>` would be inappropriate here?

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to accomplish with "something like this"? What type is `test` and what do you want to set `testname` to?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Could you show the code your class `Test` and `Pushpin`

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, a local variable name is just that, it doesn't affect the object in any way. So, how would having dynamic variable names help you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to stick my neck out here and make some wild assumptions about what you actually want.

```
class Pushpin
{
    public Pushpin() { }
    // More Pushpin-related members and methods here
}
class Test
{
    public Test(string name) { Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // More Test-related members and methods here
}
class SO23174064
{
    Dictionary<string, Pushpin> pushpins = new Dictionary<string, Pushpin>();
    public Dictionary<string, Pushpin> CreatePushpins(IEnumerable<Test> tests)
    {
        foreach (Test test in tests)
            pushpins[test.Name] = new Pushpin();
        return pushpins;
    }
}
```

Then in your main program you can use things like this:

```
    Test[] tests = new Test[] { new Test("x"), new Test("y") };
    Dictionary<string, Pushpin> pins = new SO23174064().CreatePushpins(tests);
    // use pins["x"] etc here
```

Am I close?